# Set Mako as the default template renderer in Bottle.py

Tags: python, bottle, mako

Is there a way in Bottle where I can set Mako as the default template renderer.

#### This is the code I wanted to execute:

`app.route(path='/', method='GET', callback=func, apply=[auth], template='index.html')`

#### Where:

```
func       : a function that returns a value (a dict)
auth       : is a decorator for authentication
index.html : displays the values from the "func" and contains "Mako" syntax
```

#### I have tried:

- Changing .html to .mako
- Used the `renderer` plugin: `app.route(..., renderer='mako'`)
- Tried different patterns: `# even used '.mako', 'index.mako', 'index.html.mako'`

#### Also looked inside `bottle` object but didn't saw any hint to set/change default engine:

```
# Print objects that contains "template" keyword, the object itself, and its value
for i in dir(app):
    if 'template' in i.lower():
        print '{}: {}'.format(i, getattr(app, i))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a Mako template from your route function:

```
from bottle import mako_template as template

def func():
    ...
    return template('mytemplate.mako')
```

---

EDIT:

`bottle.mako_view` may be what you're looking for.  Haven't tried it yet myself, but something like this might do the trick:

```
app.route(path='/', method='GET', callback=func, apply=[auth, mako_view('index.html')])
```

Comment: Thanks ron, but that approach is only possible if I return the values w/ Mako in the `callback` itself. What I am doing is immitating how django uses the urls.py, only that in this case, I can't seem to tell bottle to use Mako instead of it's built in template to return the view.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Perhaps `mako_view` is what you're looking for?  Answer updated.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome ron! didn't realize that mako_view can also be used in the apply filter :)

Accepted this as the answer (y)

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, there is no current way to change default template into something else, so it ended up with a temporary solution (until there is something built-in for bottle --- or until it's found).

Here's the temporary solution :

```
import bottle as app

# Suppose this is the function to be used by the route:
def index(name):
    data = 'Hello {}!'.format(name)
    return locals()

# This was the solution (decorator).
# Alter the existing function which returns the same value but using mako template:
def alter_function(func, file_):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        data = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return app.mako_template(file_, **data)

    return wrapper

# This really is the reason why there became a complexity:
urls = [
    # Format: (path, callback, template, apply, method)
    # Note: apply and method are both optional
    ('/<name>', index, 'index')
]

# These are the only key names we need in the route:
keys = ['path', 'callback', 'template', 'apply', 'method']

# This is on a separate function, but taken out anyway for a more quick code flow:
for url in urls:
    pairs = zip(keys, url)
    set_ = {}

    for key, value in pairs:
        set_.update({key:value})

    callback = set_.get('callback')
    template = set_.get('template')
    set_['callback'] = alter_function(callback, template)

    app.route(**set_)

app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import bottle

from bottle import(
        route,
        mako_view as view, #THIS IS SO THAT @view uses mako
        request,
        hook,
        static_file,
        redirect
        )

from bottle import mako_template as template #use mako template


@route("/example1")
def html_example1(name="WOW"):
    return template("<h1>Hello ${name}</h1>", name=name)

@route("/example2")
@view("example2.tpl")
def html_exampl2(name="WOW"):
    #example2.tpl contains html and mako template code like: <h1>${name}</h1>
    return {"name" : name}
```